# Tensorflow 1.0 GPU installation issue on OSX

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, spyder

I have tried to upgrade tensorflow 0.12 (cpu) to 1.0 (gpu) on a MacBook. I already had installed tensorflow (cpu) but I think I did that on an anaconda environment (did't create a new one, instead I installed it on the existing root environment).

To install the new version I followed these [steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac):

1. sudo pip uninstall tensorflow
2. pip3 install tensorflow-gpu (succesful, plus I have already installed the latest CUDA and cuDNN)

When I try to run tensorflow on spyder (iPython) or via the terminal on python initially it looks that the library is loaded but without 'extracting' the CUDA and cuDNN drivers (when you get a list with drivers or components after import tensorflow as tf). And in general I receive weird messages when I try to execute the Hello TensorFlow, `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'`

I executed: `sudo -H pip3 show tensorflow-gpu`

I received:

```
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: wheel, protobuf, six, numpy
```

So, version 1.0 GPU is installed but still I couldn't get tensorflow working. And if I had the CPU version 0.12 uninstalled where did python (and spyder) get their package from?
I looked around and I found out that I can check the location of the imported packages by using on the terminal the command python -v:

According to python when I import tensorflow I receive this message:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
# possible namespace for /Users/g****/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow
import 'tensorflow' # None
```

That's a different location from what the pip3 show command shows. Actually, I followed the path to that folder and is empty. So, I deleted the folder from anaconda and now when I execute import tensorflow on python-v I get:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Does anyone know how can I fix that? So spyder and python can see the location of tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: Please wait until `tensorflow` is distributed as conda packages because the `pip` ones don't work well with Anaconda. I've heard that's going to happen very soon (one or two weeks from now).

Comment: Hey @CarlosCordoba thanks! Actually, I just found this: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow
But, I think it's just for simple cpu's and not optimised for gpu. There was a forum discussion 
https://github.com/conda-forge/tensorflow-feedstock/issues/10

Comment: `conda-forge` packages are (for the most part) incompatible with the default Anaconda ones, so my recommendation is to wait for official packages.

Comment: are you in a directory or in a parent directory called ‘tensorflow’? what is the output of `print(tensorflow.__file___)` ?

Comment: When I was trying to type that I was getting an error...something like tensorflow doesn't include __file__, I don't really remember now. But, the problem had to do with the fact that I own a MacBook and I was trying to run it on iPython (spyder). The solution is to disable the SID on Mac, as it doesn't let iPython and TensorFlow to access CUDA files. I will post a solution later on.